# UART Interrupt of PIC32MZ

Tags: c, embedded, uart, microchip

I am doing UART interrupt and I have doubt about a short form. What is the meaning of this `IEC4bits.U2EIE = 1;` and what is this `U2EIE` means?

Answer (score 2):

The `IECx` (Interrupt Enable Control) register contains flags that enable or disable interrupt sources from triggering a CPU interrupt.

The `UxEIE` (Error Interrupt Enable Control bit) control bit in the `IECx` register, if set, is used to detect errors that occur during data flow in the UART port.

Check the documentation for more information:

1. [PIC32 Family Reference Manual - UART](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/61107G.pdf)
2. [PIC32 Family Reference Manual - Interrupts](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/60001108H.pdf)